# Why relative permittivity term is not used while writing Gauss law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, dielectric

[image]

The above question can be done by consider a cuboidal gaussian  surface at $AB$.
Now since $J_{\rho} = E$
we can calculate the flux ($\Phi_{E}$) change and then use the [Gauss law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)

change in flux: $$\Delta\Phi_{E} = \frac{q}{\varepsilon_{0} \cdot \varepsilon_{r}}$$

to calculate $q$, according to which ($B$) should be the answer but in the solution they have not considered $\varepsilon_{r}$ while writing gauss law (Answer given is $A$).Why is it so?

Comment: Why do you think the Gauss law for electric field involves relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$?